# Java Collections max NullPointerException

Tags: java, collections, java-8, nullpointerexception, max

I have java 1.8.0_171 and the following code in DataUtils.java class:

```
List<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new BigDecimal(0));
list.add(new BigDecimal(-2));
list.add(new BigDecimal(10));
list.add(new BigDecimal(200));

if ((Collections.max(list).subtract(Collections.min(list)).compareTo(new BigDecimal(0)) != 0)) {
    .....
            }
```

And I have the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   java.util.Collections.max(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.util.DataUtils.calculateRetsentindex(DataUtils.java:23)

The default jdk is set on Eclipse correctly, clean-rebuild don't fix. Please, advice

Comment: This code does not appear to raise that exception. Would you like to post a [mcve]?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your code runs nicely on my computer and does go into the `.....` part.

Comment: As an aside, to find out whether there are different values in the list, you don’t need to find min and max first. Another option is `if (list.stream().anyMatch(bd -> bd.compareTo(list.get(0)) != 0))`.

Comment: Further, to augment @OleV.V.’s comment, if you want to find out whether the two values are equal, you can just use `Collections.max(list).equals(Collections.min(list))` if you want to do it that way. Or, if you insist of using `compareTo`, how about `Collections.max(list).compareTo(Collections.min(list)) != 0` instead of `Collections.max(list).subtract(Collections.min(list)).compareTo(new BigDecimal(0)) != 0`? Your code looks like you have tried to create the maximum number of indirection possible. Though, you could have inserted an `.add(new BigDecimal(0))` somewhere in-between…

Comment: @Holger The natural ordering of `BigDecimal` is inconsistent with `equals`. The idiomatic way of comparting the values (ignoring the scales) is by `compareTo`. Otherwise your point is good. Also if one needs value of 0, I’d prefer `BigDecimal.ZERO`.

Comment: @OleV.V. you need `compareTo` when you want to check whether all object have the same value, like with your `anyMatch` approach. In contrast, the OP’s attempt is to check whether the minimum and maximum element are equal; since in that case, both, `Collections.min` and `Collections.max`, should have returned the first element of the list, even using `==` would be sufficient to conclude that there were no elements with a bigger or smaller value behind the first element, which `min` and `max` did check using `compareTo`… Still, your approach is preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that in your collection you probably have added a null element. In your example:

```
 List<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<>();
          list.add(new BigDecimal(0));
          list.add(new BigDecimal(-2));
          list.add(new BigDecimal(10));
          list.add(new BigDecimal(200));
          if ((Collections.max(list).subtract(Collections.min(list)).compareTo(new BigDecimal(0)) != 0)) {
                System.out.println("OK");
          }
```

It prints "OK" properly. If you change the first object to null though:

```
list.add(null);
```

You get similar exception to yours.

And if you do `Collections.max(null);` you get the exact same exception. So I guess your list is not initialized when you do the call.

Answer (score 2):

## Filter `null` elements out, before `::max` them:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;
...

  list.stream()
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .max(naturalOrder())
      .orElse(null);
```